# Using WAMP in react-native

Tags: javascript, react-native

I am trying to use `react-native-autobahnjs` in my `ignite` react native project, and all I get is an error:

```
Unable to resolve module 'url' from 'mypaths/node_modules/ws/lib/WebSocket.js': Module does not exist in the module map or in these directories mypaths/node_modules/ws/node_modules, mypaths/node_modules
```

What might be causing this? I have the `ws/lib` inside my `node_modules`.

Any alternatives to use WAMP inside react-native app?

Comment: it's seen like u have wrong path or wrong module name.

Answer (score 0):

React-Native doesn't have a nodejs server inside, so you  don't have access to most node modules. You can install modules, which have no dependencies.

Autobahn-js was ported by removing all it's depencies(crypto-js, when, ws, msgpack-lite), and transformed into es6 style code.
Now, it works in react-native and web browser, but not in nodejs(need ws), and only supports json protocol.
https://github.com/webee/wamp.js